# How can I get multiple counts in a single sql request?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want a count of the number of rows for each user in the table. For example, suppose I have a table like this:

```
user_id | order_id | name
--------+----------+-----
      6 |       a1 |  Joe
      6 |       b4 |  Joe
      6 |       c2 |  Joe
      6 |       d5 |  Joe
      6 |       a6 |  Joe
      8 |       b9 | Mary
      8 |       c7 | Mary
      8 |       a2 | Mary
      3 |       ba | Jack
      3 |       c3 | Jack
      3 |       a9 | Jack
      3 |       b6 | Jack
      5 |       c9 | Jill
      5 |       d2 | Jill
```

I want a result that tells me that Joe appears 5 times, Mary 3 times, Jack 4 times, and Jill twice. So I want a sql statement (preferably mySql, but any language will do), that gives results like this:

```
name | user_id | count
-----+---------+------
 Joe |       6 |     5
Mary |       8 |     3
Jack |       3 |     4
Jill |       5 |     2
```

Is there a way to do this in sql? I can't find one, but there's a lot I don't know about sql.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
Count(userid) as count
, userid
, name
From table
Group by userid, name
```

Comment: This works. I'm not sure why I should group by both userid and name. It seems like grouping just by userid would be sufficient, unless a single userid could have multiple names.

Comment: When ever we use aggregate function for any columns in select others columns are in group by simple

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS count, name FROM table_name GROUP BY name
```